# checked checkbox to enable text field with validation

Tags: javascript, checkbox, validation

I have a Paypal form which has been built using some borrowed code. The main purpose of the form is to add some optional extras to a standard product and send that data to the paypal checkout. It seems to be working quite well, but...

I have a text field that I want to be required when the related checkbox is checked and for it to be disabled, and therefore not required when its unchecked. 
Crucially I need the data in the text field to be sent to the paypal shopping basket.

I have validation on another text field which will always be required, that works and sends the data to Paypal, but I'm a javascript newbie and can't get to grips with the second field.

This is the borrowed javascript

```
function Dollar (val) {  // force to valid dollar amount
var str,pos,rnd=0;
  if (val < .995) rnd = 1;  // for old Netscape browsers
  str = escape (val*1.0 + 0.005001 + rnd);  // float, round, escape
  pos = str.indexOf (".");
  if (pos > 0) str = str.substring (rnd, pos + 3);
  return str;
}

var amt,des,obj,val,op1a,op1b,op2a,op2b,itmn;

function ChkTok (obj1) {
var j,tok,ary=new Array ();       // where we parse
  ary = val.split (" ");          // break apart
  for (j=0; j<ary.length; j++) {  // look at all items
// first we do single character tokens...
    if (ary[j].length < 2) continue;
    tok = ary[j].substring (0,1); // first character
    val = ary[j].substring (1);   // get data
    if (tok == "@") amt = val * 1.0;
    if (tok == "+") amt = amt + val*1.0;
    if (tok == "%") amt = amt + (amt * val/100.0);
    if (tok == "#") {             // record item number
      if (obj1.item_number) obj1.item_number.value = val;
      ary[j] = "";                // zap this array element
    }
// Now we do 3-character tokens...
    if (ary[j].length < 4) continue;
    tok = ary[j].substring (0,3); // first 3 chars
    val = ary[j].substring (3);   // get data
    if (tok == "s1=") {           // value for shipping
      if (obj1.shipping)  obj1.shipping.value  = val;
      ary[j] = "";                // clear it out
    }
    if (tok == "s2=") {           // value for shipping2
      if (obj1.shipping2) obj1.shipping2.value = val;
      ary[j] = "";                // clear it out
    }
  }
  val = ary.join (" ");           // rebuild val with what's left
}

function StorVal () {
var tag;
  tag = obj.name.substring (obj.name.length-2);  // get flag
  if      (tag == "1a") op1a = op1a + " " + val;
  else if (tag == "1b") op1b = op1b + " " + val;
  else if (tag == "2a") op2a = op2a + " " + val;
  else if (tag == "2b") op2b = op2b + " " + val;
  else if (tag == "3i") itmn = itmn + " " + val;
  else if (des.length == 0) des = val;
  else des = des + ", " + val;
}

function ReadForm (obj1, tst) { // Read the user form
var i,j,pos;
  amt=0;des="";op1a="";op1b="";op2a="";op2b="";itmn="";
  if (obj1.baseamt) amt  = obj1.baseamt.value*1.0;  // base amount
  if (obj1.basedes) des  = obj1.basedes.value;  // base description
  if (obj1.baseon0) op1a = obj1.baseon0.value;  // base options
  if (obj1.baseos0) op1b = obj1.baseos0.value;
  if (obj1.baseon1) op2a = obj1.baseon1.value;
  if (obj1.baseos1) op2b = obj1.baseos1.value;
  if (obj1.baseitn) itmn = obj1.baseitn.value;
  for (i=0; i<obj1.length; i++) {     // run entire form
    obj = obj1.elements[i];           // a form element
    if (obj.type == "select-one") {   // just selects
      if (obj.name == "quantity" ||
          obj.name == "amount") continue;
      pos = obj.selectedIndex;        // which option selected
      val = obj.options[pos].value;   // selected value
      ChkTok (obj1);                  // check for any specials

      if (obj.name == "on0" ||        // let this go where it wants
          obj.name == "os0" ||
          obj.name == "on1" ||
          obj.name == "os1") continue;

      StorVal ();

    } else
    if (obj.type == "checkbox" ||     // just get checkboxex
        obj.type == "radio") {        //  and radios
      if (obj.checked) {
        val = obj.value;              // the value of the selection
        ChkTok (obj1);
        StorVal ();
      }
    } else
    if (obj.type == "select-multiple") {  //one or more
      for (j=0; j<obj.options.length; j++) {  // run all options
        if (obj.options[j].selected) {
          val = obj.options[j].value; // selected value (default)
          ChkTok (obj1);
          StorVal ();
        }
      }
    } else
    if (obj.name == "size") {
      val = obj.value;                // get the data
      if (val == "" && tst) {         // force an entry
        alert ("Enter data for " + obj.name);
        return false;
      }
      StorVal ();
    } else
    if (obj.name == "stamp") {
      val = obj.value;                // get the data
      //if (val == "" && tst) {         // force an entry
      //  alert ("Enter data for " + obj.name);
      //  return false;
      //}
      StorVal ();
    }
  }
// Now summarize stuff we just processed, above
  if (op1a.length > 0) obj1.on0.value = op1a;
  if (op1b.length > 0) obj1.os0.value = op1b;
  if (op2a.length > 0) obj1.on1.value = op2a;
  if (op2b.length > 0) obj1.os1.value = op2b;
  if (itmn.length > 0) obj1.item_number.value = itmn;
  obj1.item_name.value = des;
  obj1.amount.value = Dollar (amt);
  if (obj1.tot) obj1.tot.value = "£" + Dollar (amt);
}
```

and this is the html

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="weboptions" method="post" onsubmit="this.target='_blank'; return ReadForm(this, true);">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="craig@craigomatic.co.uk" />
            <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value />
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF">

            <input type="hidden" name="basedes" value="Collar">
            <h4>Collar details...</h4>

            <div>
                <p>Matching lamb nappa lining <br />
                with antique brass finished hardware</p>
          <div>
                    <p>Pick a colour:</p>
              <p>Chose a width:</p>
                    <p>Tell us the Size:<br />
                       in cms (?)</p>
            </div>
              <div>
                <p>
                <select name="colour" onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" size="1">
                        <option value="Black +55.00">Black</option>
                        <option value="Brown +55.00">Brown</option>
                        <option value="Tan +55.00">Tan</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                <select name="width" onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" size="1">
                        <option value="1 and quarter inch">1¼ inch</option>
                        <option value="1 and half inch">1½ inch</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p><input name="size" type="text" class="size"></p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>

            </div>


            <h4>Optional extras...</h4>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <label>
                        <input type ="checkbox" onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" 
                            value   ="Double D +1.50"
                            name    ="DoubleD">
                        Double D Me (£1.50)
                    </label>
                </p>   
                <p>
                    <label>
                        <input type ="checkbox" onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" 
                            value   ="Max Me +1.50"
                            name    ="MaxMe">
                        Max Me! (£1.50)
                    </label>
                </p>
                                    <p>
                  <label>
                        <input type ="checkbox" onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" 
                            value   ="Match Me +1.50"
                            name    ="MatchMe">
                        Match Me (£1.50)
                    </label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>
                    <input type ="checkbox" onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);"
                         value  ="Stamp Me +1.50"
                         name   ="StampMe">
                         Stamp Me (£1.50)</label>
                </p>
                <p><input name="stamp" type="text" class="lettering" maxlength="12"></p>

            </div>

                <p>Total:<input class="nbor" type="text" name="tot" size="7" value="£55.00"  /> <input class="buy" type="submit" value="Buy Me" name="B1"></p>

</form>
```

If your wondering you can find the page in question here http://booleather.co.uk/option1/bronze-bronco.php

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a try:

```
if (val == "" && obj1.elements["StampMe"].checked) {
  // if the value of the stamp text field is empty and the user has checked the StampMe box
  alert ("Enter data for " + obj.name);
  return false;
}
```

(instead of)

```
  //if (val == "" && tst) {         // force an entry
  //  alert ("Enter data for " + obj.name);
  //  return false;
  //}
```

Comment: Hi James, 

Thanks, that works quite well, the validation is definitely working, but when you check the box the running total isn't generated, unless you uncheck and recheck it again, or add another option. It does however get passed to the checkout, so it is at least being totted up. 

Could it be that the error message is fired up immediately that its getting in the way of the calculation being shown, and if so is there a way to make the error message appear when the submit button is hit?

Sorry for wanting the moon on a stick

Comment: That's true Craig.  The total is calculated at the end of the function, so any field that doesn't pass validation will cause no total calculation.  Perhaps the total should read "invalid" until all of the fields pass validation?  Not sure, that's up to you.